# zipArchive : how to use it

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I have an issue with my host (and maybe my internet connection) : i use filezilla to upload several huge .zip on my website (each .zip weighs ca. 500Mo) and the connection closes before the upload's end.
So, i thought i would upload a folder containing my photographies (in that way, filezilla uploads several little files and not ONE HUGE file), and then i will make an archive of these by passing through a php script.

Here is the code i did :

```
/*
params :
string $nom_archive: archive's name in '.zip' (ex. 'archive.zip', 'test.zip', etc.)
string $adr_dossier: the path of the folder to archive (ex. 'images', '../dossier1/dossier2', etc.)
string $dossier_destination : path of the folder where we will copy/paste the archive (ex. 'images/zip', '../archives', etc.)  
DOn't change the params $zip and $dossier_base
*/

function zipper_repertoire_recursif($nom_archive, $adr_dossier, $dossier_destination = '', $zip=null, $dossier_base = '') {
    if($zip===null) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if($zip->open($nom_archive, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if(substr($adr_dossier, -1)!='/') {
        $adr_dossier .= '/';
    }

    if($dossier_base=="") {
        $dossier_base=$adr_dossier;
    }

    if(file_exists($adr_dossier)) {
        if(@$dossier = opendir($adr_dossier)) {
            while(false !== ($fichier = readdir($dossier))) {
                if($fichier != '.' && $fichier != '..') {
                    if(is_dir($adr_dossier.$fichier)) {
                        $zip->addEmptyDir($adr_dossier.$fichier);
                        zipper_repertoire_recursif($nom_archive, $adr_dossier.$fichier, $dossier_destination, $zip, $dossier_base);
                    }
                    else {
                        $zip->addFile($adr_dossier.$fichier);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if($dossier_base==$adr_dossier) {
        $zip->close();

        if($dossier_destination!='') {
            if(substr($dossier_destination, -1)!='/') {
                $dossier_destination .= '/';
            }
            if(rename($nom_archive, $dossier_destination.$nom_archive)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, i call my function that way :

```
zipper_repertoire_recursif('Myriam&Fabien_byGFernandez_Originales.zip', './Myriam&Fabien/Photos/originales/photos_originales', './Myriam&Fabien/Photos/originales')
```

But it won't work, and i don't know why.

I've checked if zip is enabled on my server and it is.
DO you have any idea on my problem?
Maybe I'm using ZipArchive the wrong way, but i can't figure out what i did wrong.
COuld you help me, please?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: none. the archive was not create and that is all... how do i use error handler with that?